# how do use variables from both django and js inside of html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
      selected_files.push(input.files.item(i))
      children += '<form id=${input.files.item(i).name}-edit-form action={% url 'asset-batch-update' %} method="POST">';
  }
```

What is the correct way to drop these js variables and django variables into html as seen on the last line of the snippet.

I tried to use ${input.files.item(i).name} for the js var and {% url 'producer:asset-batch-update' application.client_id %} is the django var, but I'm not sure if that needs to be wrapped in another pair of quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape double quotes within double quotes like so `"abc\"def\"ghi"` which will result in *abc"def"ghi*. Does that solve your question?

```
for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
     selected_files.push(input.files.item(i))
     children += "<form id=\"${input.files.item(i).name}\" -edit-form action=\"{% url 'asset-batch-update' %}\" method=\"POST\">";
}
```

Comment: so just use /" at beginning and end of variable?

Comment: This is the result you want to have: <form id="SOMETHING" -edit-form action="SOMETHING" method="POST">. In order to achieve that, you need to escape double quotes within double quotes like so \"